# When does Moment Convergence imply convergence in $L^p$?

Tags: probability-theory, lp-spaces, uniform-integrability

Under which condition does $E[X_n^2]\rightarrow E[X^2]$ impliy that $X_n\xrightarrow{L^2}X$. I think it is sufficient that $X_n$ is uniformly integrable but can't remember a proof at the moment. So is my guess correct and if not are there other conditions that satisfy this implication?

Comment: You need something about the convergence of the random variables themselves, otherwise they could be completely different random variables that just happen to have similar moments.  I think $X_n \to X$ in probability would be enough,.  Uniform integrability won't help by itself, and in any case it would only give you $L^1$ convergence.  Uniform integrability of $X_n^2$, plus convergence i.p., would give you $L^2$ convergence, but I think convergence i.p. plus your condition is already sufficient.

Comment: You are right. I just found what I was looking for. If you have convergence in probability, it is equivalent to have uniform integrability or moment convergence or L^p convergence.

Comment: Great!  You can post it as an answer below, ideally with either a proof or a reference.  Then this question can be marked as "answered".

Comment: Like Nate says, you just need convergence in probability. See proposition 12.9 here: https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/uniform_integrability.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The convergence in $\mathbb L^2$ of $\left(X_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ to $X$ is equivalent to the convergence to zero of $\mathbb E\left[\left(X_n-X\right)^2\right]$. If we have the convergence of $\mathbb E\left[ X_n ^2\right]$ to $\mathbb E\left[ X  ^2\right]$, then all we need is the following 
$$
\lim_{n\to +\infty}\mathbb E\left[ X_nX\right]=\mathbb E\left[ X^2\right].
$$